# Each csv file to divide by a specific value referring from a different csv file for normalization

Tags: python, r, linux, loops, csv

I have a folder contains multiple csv files (target_csv) to process, and a different csv file to refer a specific value in rows (reference_csv).

What I would like to do is that read a first target_csv file from a folder and divide by a value in the first row of the reference_csv and save as a new csv file.
Then, repeat until the end (read a second target_csv and it will be divided by a value in the second row of the reference_csv).

If I do one by one, the script is shown in below (This works in R).

```
d1 <- read.table("target1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
d12 <- d1[,2:25]
d13 <- as.matrix(d12)

dref <- read.table("reference.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
dref1 <- dref[1,1] #refer first row

d14 <- d13/dref1
write.csv(d14, "normalized1.csv", quote=FALSE, rownames=FALSE)

#Then, repeat as
#d2 <- read.table("target2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
#d22 <- d2[,2:25]
#d23 <- as.matrix(d22)

#dref2 <- dref[1,2] #refer second row

#d24 <- d23/dref2
write.csv(d24, "normalized2.csv", quote=FALSE, rownames=FALSE)
```

Could anyone please let me know how I can automate this process in R, python, or linux?

Answer (score 0):

In R, you may try this option -

```
dref <- read.csv("reference.csv")
#Get the values to divide in a vector
vec <- unlist(d1[1,2:25])

#Name of the target files
filenames <- list.files(pattern = 'target.*csv$')

#Read each file and divide by corresponding vector.
Map(function(x, y) {
  tmp <- read.csv(x)
  write.csv(tmp/y, sub('target', 'normalized', x), quote=FALSE, rownames=FALSE)
}, filenames, vec)
```

One check that you can perform is `length(vec)` and `length(filenames)` should return the same value.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Actually, target csv has a multiple rows and columns, which is no problem to divide by the specific value.
Thank you again and I will give it a try with your script.